# Why does Banach-Mazur compactum compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Define the Banach-Mazur distance between finite-dimensional normed space $X, Y$ as
$$d(X,Y)=\inf_{T\in\mathrm{GL}(X,Y)}\|T\|\|T^{-1}\|.$$
Let $\mathrm{BM}(n)$ denote the set of isometry class of $n$-dimensional normed space, then $\log d$ is a distance on $\mathrm{BM}(n)$.

I can understand all statements above, and I know such distance space is call Banach-Mazur compactum, but why does it compact? I think it may follow from the result
$$d(X,\ell^2_n)\leq\sqrt{n},$$
but I don't know how to go forward.